# In an Angular, how would I get bootstrap data from the server before launch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A bit of info. I'm working on a single page app, but am attempting to make it just an HTML file, rather than an actual dynamic page that contains all the bootstrap information in it. I'm also hoping to, when the app boots (or perhaps prior to), check to see if the current session is 'logged in', and if not then direct the hash to the 'login'.

I'm new to Angular, and am having a difficult time figuring out how to program out this flow. So, in essence..

1. HTML page loaded with 'deferred' bootstrap
2. Hit URL to get login status
3. If status is 'not logged in', direct to #/login
4. Start app

Any pointers on where #2 and #3 would live? In my 'easy world' I'd just use jquery to grab that data, and then call the `angular.resumeBootstrap([appname])`. But, as I'm trying to actually learn Angular rather than just hack around the parts I don't understand, I'd like to know what would be used in this place. I was looking at providers, but I'm not sure that's what I need.

Thanks!

## EDIT

Based on @Mik378's answer, I've updated my code to the following as a test. It works to a point, but as the 'get' is async, it allows the application to continue loading whatever it was before then shooting off the status results..

```
var app = angular.module('ping', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ping.controllers'
]).provider('security', function() {
    this.$get = ['$http', function($http) {
            var service = {
                getLoginStatus: function () {
                    if (service.isAuthenticated())
                        return $q.when(service.currentUser);
                    else
                        return $http.get('/login/status').then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            service.loggedIn = response.data.loggedIn;
                            console.log(service);
                            return service.currentUser;
                        });
                },
                isAuthenticated: function () {
                    return !!service.loggedIn;
                }
            };
            return service;
        }];
}).run(['security', function(security) {
        return security.getLoginStatus().then(function () {
            if(!security.isAuthenticated()) {
                console.log("BADNESS");
            } else {
                console.log("GOODNESS");
            }
        });
}]);
```

My hope was that this could somehow be completed prior to the first controller booting up so that it wasn't loading (or attempting to load) things that weren't even cleared for access yet.

## EDIT #2

I started looking into the 'resolve' property in the router, and @Mik378 verified what I was looking at. My final code that is (currently) working how I want it is as follows (appologies about the super long code block)

```
angular.module('ping.controllers', [])
        .controller('Dashboard', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log('dashboard')
        }])
        .controller('Login', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log('login')
        }]);

var app = angular.module('ping', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ping.controllers'
]).run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($root, $location) {
    $root.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
        switch(rejection) {
            case "not logged in":
                $location.path("/login"); //<-- NOTE #1
                break;
        }
    });
}]);

app.provider('loginSecurity', function() {
    this.$get = ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
            var service = {
                defer: $q.defer, //<-- NOTE #2
                requireAuth: function() { //<-- NOTE #3
                    var deferred = service.defer();
                    service.getLoginStatus().then(function() {
                        if (!service.isAuthenticated()) {
                            deferred.reject("not logged in")
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve("Auth OK")
                        }
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                },
                getLoginStatus: function() {
                    if (service.isAuthenticated()) {
                        return $q.when(service.currentUser);
                    } else {
                        return $http.get('/login/status').then(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            service.loggedIn = response.data.loggedIn;
                            console.log(service);
                            return service.currentUser;
                        });
                    }
                },
                isAuthenticated: function() {
                    return !!service.loggedIn;
                }
            };
            return service;
        }
    ];
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        console.log('Routing loading');
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'static/scripts/dashboard/template.html',
            controller: 'Dashboard',
            resolve: {'loginSecurity': function (loginSecurity) {
                return loginSecurity.requireAuth(); //<- NOTE #4
            }}
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'static/scripts/login/template.html',
            controller: 'Login'
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
}]);
```

Notes:

1. This section hooks into routing failures. In the case of a "no login", I wanted to catch the failure and pop the person over to the login page.
2. I can't get access to the $q inside of the requireAuth function, so I grabbed a reference to it. Perhaps a better way of doing this exists?
3. This function wraps up the other two - it uses the promise returned from getLoginStatus, but returns its own promise that will be rejected if the end result from the getLoginStatus winds up with the user not being logged in. Sort of a round-about way of doing it.
4. This returns #3's promise, which is used by the $routeProvider.. so if it fails, the routing fails and you end up catching it at #1.

Whew. I think that's enough for a day. Time for a beer.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to perform this check on another angular route and then perform the redirect?

Comment: Not really, no - I'm just used to checking at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a deferred bootstrap for your case:

```
angular.module('app').run(['security', '$location', function(security) {
  // Get the current user when the application starts
  // (in case they are still logged in from a previous session)
  security.requestCurrentUser().then(function(){
       if(!security.isAuthenticated())
       $location.path('yourPathToLoginPage')
     };   //service returning the current user, if already logged in
}]);
```

this method `requestCurrentUser` would be the following:

```
requestCurrentUser: function () {
                    if (service.isAuthenticated())
                        return $q.when(service.currentUser);
                    else
                        return $http.get('/api/current-user').then(function (response) {
                            service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                            return service.currentUser;
                        });
                }
```

and inside `security` service again:

```
isAuthenticated: function () {
                    return !!service.currentUser;
                }
```

Note the `run` method of the module => As soon as the application runs, this service is called.

## -- UPDATE --

To prevent any controller to be initialized before the promise provided by `requestCurrentUser` is resolved, a better solution, as evoked in the comments below, is to use the `resolve` route property .

Comment: Ah, this actually seems to make sense. Let me play around with it for a bit and I'll let you know!

Comment: OK - one thing that perhaps was an oversight (or I'm not doing something right). The '$http.get' is of course async.. which is fine because it's returning a promise object. But, calling requestCurrentUser just returns a promise object. It's not going to have that data ready by the time the next line is hit (at `if(!security.isAuthenticated())`). Now, in my code I've instead tapped into the promise object to do that inside of a `.then`, but it doesn't really prevent the loading of any other controllers or get done before the application is really launched.

Comment: And since I'm limited to only 600 chars.. part 2. Was the intention to tap into some sort of angular magic that would wait for the promise object to return before doing something? I've updated what I have so far in my question (or at least I will in a few minutes).

Comment: @Stephen To wait for the promise, you should rather use the `resolve` route property on the configuration of the first controller's module. Something like:  `resolve: security.requestCurrentUser`.  One example here: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out about that. I think it'll do the trick.

Comment: @Stephen Cool :) I think so!

Comment: Alright. You put me on the right track, so answer accepted :P Thanks for your time.